# WooCommerce - GET Order API filter with Order "meta_data" property using Postman

Tags: woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I'm using Postman to get WooCommerce orders in an environment that I've setup locally for testing purposes. I need to know if there is a way where I could filter the orders by custom field values (meta_data fields)? I could not find any documentation on this matter.

I tried below in Postman but it did not give the result I expected. Since the `is_vat_exempt` value was set to `no`, and it still gave me results in the Order response:

```
GET http://localhost/woosite/wp-json/wc/v3/orders?meta_key='is_vat_exempt'&meta_value='yes'
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently it is not possible. unless you create your own function using the available filter **woocommerce_rest_orders_prepare_object_query**

https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-rest-api-controllers-version2-class-wc-rest-network-orders-v2-controller.html

Similar solution is here [Woocommerce REST API exclude specific product oder in orders endpoints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63173481/woocommerce-rest-api-exclude-specific-product-oder-in-orders-endpoints) and here [WooCommerce REST API - Filter Orders By Date Modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42531523/woocommerce-rest-api-filter-orders-by-date-modified)

```
add_filter('woocommerce_rest_orders_prepare_object_query', 'eg_change_list_order_result_woorestapiv3', 10, 2);
function eg_change_list_order_result_woorestapiv3 (array $args, \WP_REST_Request $request){
        $mdk = $request->get_param('meta_data_key');
        $mdv = $request->get_param('meta_data_value');
        
        if (  !isset( $mdk ) ) {
            return $args;
        }

        if ( ! empty( $args['meta_query'] ) ) {
            $args['meta_query'] = array();
        }

        if ( isset( $mdk ) && !isset( $mdv ) ) {

            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'   => $mdk,
            );
            
        }elseif ( isset( $mdk ) && isset( $mdv ) ) {

            $args['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'   => $mdk,
                'value' => $mdv,
            );
            
        }

        return $args;

    }
```

Put your code in functions.php

tested and work
https://sampledomain.com/wp-json/wc/v3/orders/?meta_data_key=samplekey&meta_data_value=samplevalue